# Why are the line spacing not the same?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a div with a background of a piece of paper and I would like to use some paragraphs to write on the lines of the paper. I have set margins to zero and I have line spacing set to 25.5px and that works perfectly on Firefox but on on Chrome. Is there a specific reason why?

Here is an image of the two side by side: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/172018499005317120/356360953392136192/unknown.png

And here is a little bit of code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="paper">
    <h1>LANO Project</h1>
    <p>Welcome to the 5th rebuild of LANO Project. I hope you like all of the upgrades that have been going on. I have worked very hard on this update to make it look very clean and avaliable for the future. I tried my best to address issues that I have noticed in the past while pushing a fun interface for the user while still making it easy for the developer to add, update, change, and sometimes remove things. I was going for a 90's theme, things that you find in the 90's.</p>
    <p>In future updates (hopefully thoses exist) I will be adding a few more entirely unnessissary physics to some of the elements found in this website. I really want my own website (this one) to be a great example of what I can do / make as a webdeveloper. I will also be adding any games I make on this site.</p>
    <p>To get started just click on the tiles in the navigation bar.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#paper{
    background: url("../home/paper.png");
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 658px;
    height: 946px;
}
#paper h1{
    margin: 0px;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 36px;
    padding-top: 75px;
    padding-left: 110px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    font-family: 'write_bold';
}
#paper p{
    margin:0px;
    line-height: 1.1;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #333333;
    text-indent: 20px;
    padding-left: 103px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    font-family: 'write';
}
```

Here is a live version if needed: http://lano-project.org/update/home/

EDIT: Added live version.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't reset initial values for margin, padding, line-height and such attributes... So browsers act differently.
To be sure, Inspect elements one by one and see they inherit their styles from where.

Google "CSS reset" for more information.
There are some prewritten reset you can get those from here:
[cssreset.com](http://cssreset.com/)
Or write your own minimal version.

**Edit:**

Also add a fixed background-size to `#paper` element.

Comment: After adding a css reset it seems to have helped some but it is still a off a little like chrome is adding a pixel to each line. Do you think the custom font is messing it up?

Comment: No, I believe it's because of the ratios(background-image height to line-height -> 946÷25.5 = 37.09 pixels) Number has Decimals, Also there is a extra space before first line so first you should measure background-image in a sketch app. The problem is the background.